# htaccess weird revert happening with a url rewrite rule and a 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having issues trying to do a 301 redirect in my htaccess file. It is having a problem working with a part of my rewrite rules I have created. In summary, the rewrite strips the extension off of the page and replaces the query ?primary-view=city to /city. Here is my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect /page.php to /page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(page)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]
# Internally forward /page to /page.php
RewriteRule ^(page)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
# Redirect /page.php?primary-view=value to /page/value
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(page)\.php\?primary-view=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]
# Internally forward /page/value to /page.php?primary-view=value
RewriteRule ^(page)/(.*)/?$ /$1.php?primary-view=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# Redirect /chicago-downtown to /chicago
Redirect 301 /chicago-downtown to /chicago
```

So the url after the rewrite will look something like

```
#Original url
example.com/page.php?primary-view=chicago-downtown
#Url rewritten properly
example.com/page/chicago
```

If I type in example.com/page/chicago then it works fine. If I type in example.com/page/chicago-downtown its currently redirecting to the following:

```
#Current bad redirect from example.com/page/chicago-downtown
example.com/page/chicago?primary-view=chicago-downtown
#Desired redirect from example.com/page/chicago-downtown
example.com/page/chicago
```

I have tried man things and came to the conclusion that it is the following line causing the issue with the 301 redirect.

```
# Internally forward /page/value to /page.php?primary-view=value
RewriteRule ^(page)/(.*)/?$ /$1.php?primary-view=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Is there some way I can rewrite my rewrite rules, or is there a rewrite condition I need to use to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `Redirect` rule. Just an additional `mod_rewrite` rule for `chicago-downtown => chicago`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(page/chicago)-downtown/?$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]

# Redirect /page.php to /page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(page)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /page to /page.php
RewriteRule ^(page)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA,NC]

# Redirect /page.php?primary-view=value to /page/value
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(page)\.php\?primary-view=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /page/value to /page.php?primary-view=value
RewriteRule ^(page)/(.*)/?$ /$1.php?primary-view=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, this did work but is this the best answer? Our company is constantly changing their links throughtout the year everytime our SEO team wants to tweak it. Will I have to just constantly make rewrite rules with this method?

Comment: You must definitely avoid mixing `mod_rewrite` and `mod_alias` rules. Also change 302 to 301 once you verify everything. Also changing link for same content is not good for SEO purpose.

Comment: Send all of them to attend a SEO session :)

Comment: Funny thing is they actually went to a seo conference in Seattle a month or two ago. Anyway, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused because you're mixing mod_alias directives with mod_rewrite directives. That means both directives get applied to the same request in an unwanted way. Remove the `Redirect` directive (mod_alias) and user a rewrite rule instead. But you need to add the rule *before* your other rules (i.e. right after `RewriteEngine On`)

```
RewriteRule ^chicago-downtown(.*)$ /chicago$1 [L,R=301]
```